# jQuery AutoComplete not working

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I got the code from [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

the Code is not working, I have the autoComplete plugin as well, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nfkt4/6/) link to it.

What's the problem and how can I solve it?

ok this is what I've written in VS

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="script/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="tags" type="text" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and it still doesn't work, sorry if it's a stupid mistake !
still doesn't work

Comment: Oh common, someone tell me what's wrong ! have to get it done at the earliest ! and I'm stuck coz of something stupid which I'm not able to figure out

Comment: Now I see ui but not jquery Make sure you include both and that jqury is loaded first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay,

1) restart VS, it has the tendency to screw up sometimes.

2) you need to include all the jquery you're going to use not just the UI plug-in

3) remember it's very important the order in which you include your plug-ins(JQuery should be #1 followed by the other plug-ins)

and keep a debugger, and check what's happening ! :)

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Very late answer but I got stuck on the exact same problem. I still do not know why (hence why I'm still searching for this), but downgrading jQuery version from 1.6.2 to 1.4.2 made it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `jQuery` in your Fiddle

Comment: damn, took time to figure out you meant jQuery ! anyways, thanks, it's working on fiddle, hope it works on VS !

Comment: Lol sorry that ws iPad trying to help correct spelling and I didn't notice

Comment: haha, never mind :) have updated my answer, would be grateful if you could tell me what's wrong with it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that the 'fiddle' link doesn't work (haven't used that before - nifty!) because the fiddle page seems to only have 'jquery' loaded, not 'jqueryui'?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the jQuery UI framework as well. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nfkt4/7/)
And here's where you can get the [jQuery UI](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI)

Comment: @heymecarter have updated my code to the answer, it's till not working, what should I do?

Comment: @manPej the only thing i can tell you is try and remove the script for the autocorrect and just include jquery and jqueryui and get both of them from google using the link in my answer. I ran it on my dev server and it works fine minus css styling